# Can nodejs stdout be written to such that the receiving nodejs stdin `on-data` returns individual segments?

Tags: node.js, stream, stdout, stdin

I have a nodejs script generating a set of objects in a more secure environment and then piping the result to the long-running application, I was hoping this could also provide a way to pass iterable objects by having the stringification/parsing be done by the js and leave the structure transparent on my first script.

Right now I've been trying to create a readable stream from my iterable, or directly write each section with `process.stdout.write()` but in both instances, receiving it with `process.stdin.on('data', (chunk) => do something with chunk` always results in the all the strings combined.

```js
let env = {
   variableString: "somekey",
   someIterable: {
      someOtherValue: ['more values']
   }
}

let streamArr = [];
for (let x in env) {
    let y = env[x].replace(/ {4}/g ,'')
    streamArr.push(JSON.stringify({[x]:y}))
}
// const readable = new Stream.Readable()
// readable.pipe(process.stdout)
streamArr.forEach(item => process.stdout.write(item))
```

```js
// Receiving script
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
process.stdin.on('data', (chunk) => {
    console.log(chunk)
    let i = JSON.parse(chunk);
    for (let x in i) {
        if(typeof i[x] == 'string') process.env[x] = i[x];
        console.log(x)
    }
});

process.stdin.on('end', () => {
  console.log('end')
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended sort of sidestepping this issue, since my data was small enough I just wrote the whole object to STDOUT using

```javascript
process.stdout.write(JSON.stringify(env))
```

And then using the `fs` module to receive STDIN since it's the only way I found to synchronously consume the STDIN to initialize environment variables before anything else runs.

```javascript
const fs = require('fs')
const env = (function () {
    let envTmp = fs.readFileSync(0).toString();
    envTmp = JSON.parse(envTmp);
    return envTmp;
})();
```